# How to publish hadoop-dist-*.tar.gz with maven

Tags: maven, hadoop, hdfs, artifactory

We use maven to publish hadoop artifacts to an Artifactory installation.  By default, the jars are published, but we'd also like the hadoop-dist tarball published.

To publish the JARs, we run something like this:

> mvn -e 'clean package deploy' -Pdist -DskipTests -Dtar -Dmaven.javadoc.skip

This does build the hadoop-dist tarball, but doesn't publish it.

What extra args do we need to get the dist tarball published too?

Updated: Dist profile included below, as per request in the comments.

```
<profile>
  <id>dist</id>
  <!-- Profile for generating all maven artifacts and documentation. -->                                                                    
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        <inherited>false</inherited>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <!-- build aggregate javadoc in parent only -->
            <id>default-cli</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>aggregate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <overview>hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/java/overview.html</overview>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

Comment: what's in 'dist' profile?

Comment: Hi Mikhail, I've just added that info as an update to the original question.  Thanks for your interest

Comment: What are you doing exactly? Are you building hadoop sources? Or packing all hadoop deps into a tar archive?

Comment: What am I doing, or what do I want to do?  I think the latter is covered in the question.  In terms of what I currently do, we build hadoop for source because we have some custom modifications.  I'd like to automatically upload the created dist tarball to a maven repo, much like apache.org or cloudera seem to.